# I am having problems creating the classes for elements inside a table

Tags: html, css

I am having problems creating the css classes for tr_item, id_cell, time_cell, name_cell inside a table.

```
                        <table width="300px" colspan="4"  class="info">
                            <thead >
                                <tr colspan="4">
                                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                                    <th class="time">Time</th>
                                    <th class="name">Event</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody colspan="4">
                                <tr class="tr_item">
                                    <th class="id_cell">1234</th>
                                    <th class="time_cell">11:22</th>
                                    <th class="name_cell">ABC-DEF</th>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: What are your problems? Shouldn't the `colspan="4"` be on a `th` or `td`? I don't think it does anything on the `tbody` or `tr`.

Comment: oh ok... but the problem im having is that im not managing to link the class .id_cell, I am doing : table tbody tr.id_cell : and still nothing

Comment: @JesperScerri you don't have any `tr` elements with the class `id_cell` you want the selector to be `table tbody tr th.id_cell` or just th.id_cell.  The th elements should be td btw

Answer (score 0):

This what you are looking to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/raghn/

```
  .tr_item{
    background-color: red;
}

.tr_item th:first-child{
    background-color: blue;
}

 <table width="300px" colspan="4"  class="info">
                            <thead >
                                <tr colspan="4">
                                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                                    <th class="time">Time</th>
                                    <th class="name">Event</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody colspan="4">
                                <tr class="tr_item">
                                    <th class="id_cell">1234</th>
                                    <th class="time_cell">11:22</th>
                                    <th class="name_cell">ABC-DEF</th>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: yeah that is one that i am trying to do also the classes in <th>

Comment: Its useless. its like the class is not even created. for example .tr_item is not even working. Im going crazy

Comment: thank you all for the help... but i decided to discard the table and use divs instead.. everything is working fine now